# In Inbox by Gmail, how can recipients be moved back and forth between the To and CC fields?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

When using the ordinary Gmail web app, I can drag and drop recipients between To: and CC:

It doesn't seem possible in Inbox by Gmail web app. How can I move recipient to CC without typing in the name manually?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was shut down in April, 2019, and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is currently not possible.

Inbox by Gmail *is* currently in limited preview, so it doesn't surprise me that a lot of features aren't yet implemented. This seems like one they'd be sure to include, especially since it's such a no-brainer in regular Gmail.